# Get USB device information using boost (platform-independent)

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, usb

I'm writing a c++ library that accesses multiple devices (cameras, micro-controllers...) and I'm trying to automatize the detection of each device without having to hard-code it's serial port.

Is there a way with boost (.asio) to get a list of connected usb devices and also information about them (like uuid, etc.) ?

Thanx

p.s. platform-independence is a requirement ;)

Comment: USB is a part of the Hardware which is handled by the OS's kernel... I doubt there is a platform-independent library

Comment: Not boost, but there's [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/)

Comment: libusb looks cool. Thanx, I'll give it a try!